# How to determine the line equation of $2$ intersecting planes

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

Determine the interaction of the line of intersection of the planes [$1$] $x + y - z = 1$ and [$2$] $3x + y + z = 3$ with the line of intersection of the planes [$3$] $2x - y + 2z = 4$ and [$4$] $2x + 2y + z = 1$.

That is the question.

Ok So I need to find out the equation of the line between [$1$] and [$2$] and the equation of a second line between [$3$] and [$4$].

I know how to figure out what kind of interaction two lines have in $3$ space, so please help me solve for the first part of the question; Finding a line equation between two planes.

So my on-line course has provided an explanation on this but I can't make sense of it.

So the way I need to solve this is to use elimination between the two planes, and then I have to make one of the variables a parameter t. and then... I am lost. (please provide an explanation using the method I so vaguely described)

So again, I need two line equations, for the interaction of [$1$] and [$2$], and the planes [$3$] and [$4$].

Please help,

Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start. From your first two plane equations, you can add $x+y-x=1$ to $3x+y+z=3$ to come at $4x+2y=4$ or simplify to $2x+y=2$ Now use a parameter $t$ to set $x=t$ which gives you $y=2-2t$ Substituting these equations into one of the two given plane equations (I picked the second one), you get $z=3-3t-(2-2t)$ which gives $z=1-t$ Now you have a parametric set of the line as an intersection of the first two planes. You can do the same thing for the other two planes. Once you have two lines, you can find if there exists a value of $t$ that "matches" with all $x,y,z$ components of the two lines. You give this a try...

Comment: How do you know, which variable (xyz) has to be set to t?

Comment: Normally you have choice. This is not unique. I picked $x=t$ because the coefficient of $x$ is $1$

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll try formulate a line equation for the set [3] & [4]

Comment: Yes, try a subtraction, it makes the $x$ term disappear...

Comment: I did  [3] - [4], and got z = 3+3t when I made y = t. How do I find x? Edit: i subed my defenition of y and z into [4] and got 2x = -2-5t, Should not I try to get a x = iouoiu istead of 2x = iouoiu

Comment: With y=t and z=3+3t you can put that in any of the two equations to get the x term. If I take your equation [3], that would be $2x-t+2(3+3t)=4$ You can solve this for x now

Comment: Ok, but I have never before got an x value that has a fraction in it, I'm just a bit sceptical about my answer because I get x = -1 - (5/2)t, and I have never had a fraction as a component of a direction vector.

Comment: while not elegant, you are allowed to have a fractional component in parametric form. Now if you set, for example, the $z$ components equal to each other, you can find a $t$ value. For this $t$ value you should get the $y$ and $x$ value from your other components. Note, if there is a "mismatch", meaning that for this $t$ value you get different $x$ components or $y$ components, then the lines do not meet.

Comment: Ok, thanks a a lot!